# Why does ReactSelect cause the input to have the same key for same values entered?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a multi input field using **React Select**.

```
<ReactSelect
        aria-label="aria-select-field"
        styles={{
          multiValueRemove: () => ({
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            color: '#516382',
            cursor: 'pointer',
          }),
          multiValue: (defaultStyles) => ({
            ...defaultStyles,
            backgroundColor: '#ebeef5',
            borderRadius: '16px',
            padding: '0 12px',
            height: '32px',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginTop: '3.7px',
          }),
        }}
        id={name}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        components={{
          ClearIndicator: () => <span />,
          IndicatorSeparator: () => <span />,
          DropdownIndicator: () => <span />,
        }}
        value={(value as string[]).map((x, index) => ({ value: x, label: x, key: index }))}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        isMulti
        menuIsOpen={false}
        isDisabled={disabled}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.key === 'Tab') {
            const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
            if (target.value) {
              onChange([...(value as string[]), target.value]);
              setInputValue('');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
          } else if ((e.key === 'Backspace' || e.key === 'Delete') && disableDeselect && !error) e.preventDefault();
        }}
        onInputChange={(e, actionMeta: InputActionMeta) => {
          setInputValue(e);
          if (actionMeta.action !== 'input-blur' && actionMeta.action !== 'menu-close') onFocus();
        }}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.map((x) => x.value))}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={(e) => {
          const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
          if (target.value) {
            onChange([...(value as string[]), target.value]);
            setInputValue('');
          }
          onFocus();
        }}
      />
```

When i enter two same values, i get this error in the console:

*Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `abc-abc`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.*

Even though I have included the key in the value:

```
value={(value as string[]).map((x, index) => ({ value: x, label: x, key: index }))}
```

How can I have a unique key for each value?

Comment: can you provide which package `select` you used? maybe link or full name with version

Comment: yes it's "react-select": "^5.5.9",

Comment: I have no idea, maybe package owner takes no account of duplicate item,you can opening an issue.

Comment: Okay. thanks for looking into it.